# How to persist an Enum Value instead of the Ordinal

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, converters, ordinals

I am trying to persist in the database the value of ack(Enum) but when it's persisted, it takes the ordinal value instead of the value itself. What can i Do to save the value instead of Ordinal? here are my classes :

Converter

```
@Convert
public class AnomalieAckConverter implements AttributeConverter<AnomalieAck, Integer> {

    /**
     * @param attribute
     * @return
     * @see javax.persistence.AttributeConverter#convertToDatabaseColumn(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(AnomalieAck anoAck) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return anoAck.getValue();
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param dbData
     * @return
     * @see javax.persistence.AttributeConverter#convertToEntityAttribute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public AnomalieAck convertToEntityAttribute(Integer ack) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return AnomalieAck.getByValue(ack);

        return null;

    }
```

Enum :

```
public enum AnomalieAck {

    NON_ACQUITTEE(0),

    ACQUITTEE_APP1 (1),

    ACQUITTEE_APP2(2),

    /** Aacquittee en erreur. */
    ACQUITTEE_ERREUR(10),


    private int ack = 0;

  private AnomalieAck() {

    }

  private AnomalieAck(final int value) {
    this.ack = value;
   }
  public int getValue() {
        return this.ack;
    }

  public void setAck(int ack) {
        this.ack = ack;
    }

public static AnomalieAck getByValue(int ackNumero) {
    for (final AnomalieAck ackitement : AnomalieAck.values()) {

        if (ackitement.getValue() == ackNumero) {
            return ackitement;
        }
    }
```

Java class :

```
@Column(name = "ANO_ACK")
@Convert(converter = AnomalieAckConverter.class)
private AnomalieAck ack = AnomalieAck.NON_ACQUITTEE;
```

Is there a way to let hibernate persist the value instead of the ordinal value ?

Answer (score 2):

Testing locally with this converter:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class AnomalieAckConverter implements AttributeConverter<AnomalieAck, Integer>
    {

        @Override
        public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(final AnomalieAck attribute)
        {
            return attribute.getValue();
        }


        @Override
        public AnomalieAck convertToEntityAttribute(final Integer dbData)
        {
            return AnomalieAck.getByValue(dbData);
        }
}
```

and this entity field definition

```
    @Column(name = "ANO_ACK")
    @Convert(converter = AnomalieAckConverter.class)
    private AnomalieAck ack = AnomalieAck.ACQUITTEE_ERREUR;
```

then the ack value in the enum is persisted rather than the ordinal. Are the code examples you have provided reproducing the issue for you?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the problem is that i can't use  @Enumerated(EnumType.String) neither the ordinal, because the  field in the database is declared as a Number and i can't change that because there are a lot of  other resources that use the same Integer value.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your original question, is it the ack field in the enum that you want to persist?

Comment: My original understanding was that you wanted to persist the name of the enum. Does using the AttributeConverter not correctly map the value once you have correctly filled out the methods?

Comment: Yes it inserts the ordinal value instead of the value of the filed

Comment: @ZakariaMarrah I have tested this out locally and it is correctly parsing the ack value for me. I tested it with ACQUITTEE_ERREUR as in your example that is the only enum value without the ack matching the ordinal. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class AnomalieAckConverter 
implements 
AttributeConverter<AnomalieAck, 
Integer> {


    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(AnomalieAck 
anoAck) {
      if(anoAck != null)
        return anoAck.getValue();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // return anoAck.getValue();
      return null;
   }

/**
 * @param dbData
 * @return
 * @see javax.persistence.AttributeConverter#convertToEntityAttribute(java.lang.Object)
 */
    @Override
    public AnomalieAck convertToEntityAttribute(Integer ack) {
    // TODO filtering and returning the enum instance
    
      if(ack != null)
        return Stream.of(AnomalieAck.values())
     .filter(data -> data.getValue() == ack).findFirst().orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);

      return null;

}
```

Entity field definition

```
private AnomalieAck ack;
```

Use setter method to inject the ack in your service class.

Comment: I don't follow your answer, can you add an explanation in plain english ? (this is in general a better way to answer than just post code :D )

Comment: I don't follow your answer, can you add an explanation in plain english ? (this is in general a better way to answer than just post code :D )

Comment: One have to go for this converter approach **when there are high chances of changing the order of enums/renaming/value change**. Generally, people will go for **_Enum.ORDINAL_ / _Enum.String_** when mapping from Java object to pesistent object. The problem with the ordinal approach is, if there are any chance like I listed in bold, you'll **lose the consistency of the model** as ordinal uses some internal index to refer the enums. And with the string, you cannot do renaming enums and also it takes extra space. That's why **this approach is preferred mapping to and from entity**.